# Android: Tabbed activity with bluetooth and graph plotting, how to?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I am very new to Android, but I would like to develop my own app for a future project. The basic idea of this is to have 2 tabs (for now).

The first tab, Bluetooth, will have a button to establish a connection between Android and a bluetooth module.

The second tab, Graph, needs to read the input stream and take this data to plot a graph against time.

**Now my question is:**

Where exactly do I need to do what?

1. MainActivity handles the creation of the tabs
2. BluetoothTab inflates the layout of bluetooth_tab.xml
3. Graph inflates the layout of graph_tab.xml

My problem right now is that I don't know where to put the bluetooth connection stuff. Do I put it in the MainActivity?

If I do place the bluetooth connection stuff in the MainActivity, how can I make use of it from within the BluetoothTab fragment?

Could someone point me in the right direction with maybe an example of how this is usually done?

Here some code:

**MainActivity**

```
package com.bavilo.braumeister;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    /* Declaring Your View and Variables */

    Toolbar toolbar;
    ViewPager pager;
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
    SlidingTabLayout tabs;
    CharSequence Titles[] = {"Bluetooth","Graph"};
    int Numboftabs = 2;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Creating The Toolbar and setting it as the Toolbar for the activity
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        // Creating The ViewPagerAdapter and Passing Fragment Manager, Titles fot the Tabs and Number Of Tabs.
        adapter =  new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),Titles,Numboftabs);

        // Assigning ViewPager View and setting the adapter
        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Assiging the Sliding Tab Layout View
        tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true); // To make the Tabs Fixed set this true, This makes the tabs Space Evenly in Available width

        // Setting Custom Color for the Scroll bar indicator of the Tab View
        tabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
            @Override
            public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
                return getResources().getColor(R.color.tabsScrollColor);
            }
        });

        // Setting the ViewPager For the SlidingTabsLayout
        tabs.setViewPager(pager);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        switch(id) {
            case R.id.menu_info:

                new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("About").setMessage("Hello").show();
                break;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**BluetoothTab**

```
package com.bavilo.braumeister;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.UUID;

public class BluetoothTab extends Fragment {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bluetooth_tab,container,false);
        text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text);
        return v;
    }
}
```

**Graph**

```
package com.bavilo.braumeister;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Tab2 extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_2,container,false);
        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: Removed extra spaces in code

Answer (score 0):

All BT connection associated logic should definitely go into `MainActivity` because both tabs are going to use it. The best way to do it is to define a callback interface that `MainActivity` will implement, which will allow the `Fragments` to access the BT related functionality.

Keep the logic in `Fragments` to minimum. For example: the first `Fragment` will just register `OnClickListener` with the button, and call one of the callback methods of `MainActivity` (this method will initiate BT connection).

The steps involved are very similar to ones explained here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html